# Multiple comparisons with geom_signif function, R

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, statistics, pairwise

The package `ggsignif` is very useful for quickly and easily indicating significant comparisons in `ggplot` graphs. However the `comparisons` call requires manual typing of each pair of values to be compared.

**Eg.**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)

data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("versicolor", "virginica"),c('versicolor','setosa')), 
              map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

[image]

I'm wondering how this could be circumvented by referring to all the possible combinations at once? For example, `expand.grid(x = levels(iris$Species), y = levels(iris$Species))`, gives all the combinations

```
           x          y
1     setosa     setosa
2 versicolor     setosa
3  virginica     setosa
4     setosa versicolor
5 versicolor versicolor
6  virginica versicolor
7     setosa  virginica
8 versicolor  virginica
9  virginica  virginica
```

But how to have this accepted by `geom_signif(comparisons=...`?

Package info is available here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsignif/index.html

Comment: `combn(levels(iris$Species), 2)` will give you all three pairwise combinations

Comment: @AdamQuek using that without `list()` gives the error, `Warning message:
Computation failed in stat_signif(): not enough 'y' observations`. Using with `list()` only adds the first comparison to the plot.

Comment: Not answering your query on `geom_signif` (never used it and don't intend to). Just suggesting that `combn` is the more sensible way to get pairwise combination instead of `expand.grid`.

Comment: @AdamQuek Oh. Well thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the comment of Adam Quek you just need to transpose the created matrix and turn each row into a list:

```
split(t(combn(levels(iris$Species), 2)), seq(nrow(t(combn(levels(iris$Species), 2)))))

$`1`
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor"

$`2`
[1] "setosa"    "virginica"

$`3`
[1] "versicolor" "virginica" 

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = split(t(combn(levels(iris$Species), 2)), seq(nrow(t(combn(levels(iris$Species), 2))))), 
              map_signif_level = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Might I trouble you to ask how you could dodge or jitter those lines?

Comment: Ah, I see `step_increase=`.